Non-resolvable parent POM and parent.relativePath points at wrong local POM
Doing some study project and while building and pushing the Docker image for module inquiry-service-app in the workflow I am getting the issue with parent POM.
Error: ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.iprody:inquiry-service-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.iprody:inquiry-service:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 10 -> [Help 2]

This is the structure...

This is parent POM (inquiry-service)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <modules>
        <module>inquiry-service-app</module>
        <module>e-2-e</module>
    </modules>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.iprody</groupId>
    <artifactId>inquiry-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>inquiry-service</name>
    <description>Microservice for Inquiry Service</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


This is of the child POM (inquiry-service-app)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>inquiry-service</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.iprody</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>inquiry-service-app</artifactId>


This is docker file for module inquiry-service-app...
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17-slim AS builder
WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

FROM openjdk:17-slim
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/target/inquiry-service-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/inquiry-service-app.jar

EXPOSE 8585
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/inquiry-service-app.jar"]

This is the workflow file
name: Publish Docker Image

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "**"

env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}

jobs:
  build-and-push-image:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v4
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'
          cache: maven

      - name: Build project
        run: mvn clean package

      - name: Log in to the Container registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}

      - name: Build and push Docker image for inquiry-service-app
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          context: ./inquiry-service-app
          file: ./inquiry-service-app/Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}-inquiry-service-app
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}

      - name: Build and push Docker image for e-2-e
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          context: ./e-2-e
          file: ./e-2-e/Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}-e-2-e
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}

When I do mvn clean and install locally it builds succesfully
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for inquiry-service 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] inquiry-service .................................... SUCCESS [  2.406 s]
[INFO] inquiry-service-app ................................ SUCCESS [  9.548 s]
[INFO] e-2-e .............................................. SUCCESS [  4.561 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 

All 3 models there in .m2

meta data local

This is what I have in .m2/wrapper/dist

This is settings



I read other posts related to the same issue but could not find any solutions.
What I tried these below:

To show paths in parent POM

<relativePath/>
<relativePath>..</relativePath>
<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
<relativePath>../inquiry-service/pom.xml</relativePath>

...but it did not work

To add to the workflow mvn clean install -N before mvn clean package
...but it did not work

To add setting.xml to .m2. Actually, I did not find setting.xml in .m2 but I found it m2\wrapper\dists\apache-maven-3.8.7-bin\1ktonn2lleg549uah6ngl1r74r\apache-maven-3.8.7\conf
So I just copy paste it inside.m2\repository
...but it did not work

Some advised to delete the whole .m2 folder. But will it impact to my other projects as well? Or should I try to remove only related folder iprody (in .m2\repository\com\iprody)


Any ideas???
